# Syncing macports between machines

Tags: mac, git, sync, macports

On Mac OS. I use three different machines (work, laptop and home). I currently use git to store my dot files and to keep them synced. I have previously used homebrew to install software with a saved script to git. Is there any way to integrate macports into this, perhaps by having a script that I update and run with macports to install/update software?

I am keen to use macports as I do not like having to change permissions on /user/local/ for homebrew. It is possible that the three machines may have different versions of Mac OS on them.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Might be overkill, but you could use Puppet to keep the configuration of the machines in sync.  Unless Macports itself has a way to define a config file and you git-sync that between machines, you will need to implement some other scripting yourself, like Puppet.

Comment: In general yes - but not if they have different versions of macOS